# Change new projects warning level in VS2008 (Express)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I like having my warning level set at W4 but all new projects start at W3.  Is there some way to change the default value for warning levels for new projects?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it at the IDE but you cand always edit the new project templates at:

```
%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\
```

If you're using the express version there could be a minor variation in the path:

```
%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\{Version}\ProjectTemplates\
```

Where {Version} is the express flavor you are using, VCSExpress, VBExpress, etc.

The templates are zip files, just edit the project changing:

```
<WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
```

to

```
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```

Comment: What file types are the templates?  Neither of those directories exist on my machine.

Comment: The templates are csproj files inside a zip file, like 1033.zip

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any project templates or anything on my machine so I just searched in all the files for WarningLevel.  I found common.js at

```
%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCWizards\1033
```

Searching in the file showed WarningLevel appeared in three places, lines 672, 699 and 3354.  I simply changed the three lines reading

```
CLTool.WarningLevel = WarningLevel_3;
```

to

```
CLTool.WarningLevel = WarningLevel_4;
```

When I made a new project it was set at /w4.  So this worked for me, won't guarantee it won't hose your machine.